# No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain message

Tags: javascript, iframe, social-networking, google-plus-one, social-media

I have a page having the social bar buttons on the top and also have video which renders through  tag which contains Third party social bar.on loading the iframe video the error is coming as below.Not sure why the error is coming.I googled the error I found the reasons as because of JS API conflicts and RPC error.I can't find the fix around this error.Can anyone help me please.

```
No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain    message
bd()cb=gapi.loaded_0 (line 117)
a = 3
c = "No relay set (used as w...nd cross-domain message"
 ed()cb=gapi.loaded_0 (line 118)
 a = "No relay set (used as w...nd cross-domain message"
 xb()cb=gapi.loaded_0 (line 193)
 a = ".."
  c = "wistia_embed"
 d = Object { s="_noop_echo", f="wistia_embed", c=1, more...}
 Vb()cb=gapi.loaded_0 (line 210)
 a = ".."
 c = "_noop_echo"
 d = a(a)
  e = undefined
 xg()
```